# Check whether an Object contains a specific value in any of its array

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, ecmascript-5

How to find if an object has a value?

My Object looks like below: I have to loop through the object array and check if an array has "SPOUSE" in its value. if exist `set a flag spouseExits = true` and `store the number (in this case (4 because [SPOUSE<NUMBER>] NUMBER is 4) in a variable 'spouseIndex'`

**This function needs to render in IE9 as well.**

```
eligibilityMap = {
    "CHIP": [
        "CHILD5"
    ],
    "APTC/CSR": [
        "SELF1",
        "CHILD2",
        "CHILD3",
        "SPOUSE4"
    ]
}
```

## Code:

```
Object.keys(eligibilityMap).reduce(function (acc, key) {
  const array1 = eligibilityMap[key];
  //console.log('array1', array1);
  array1.forEach(element => console.log(element.indexOf('SPOUSE')))
  var spouseExist = array1.forEach(function (element) {
    //console.log('ex', element.indexOf('SPOUSE') >= 0);
    return element.indexOf('SPOUSE') >= 0;
  });
  //console.log('spouseExist', spouseExist);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

SpouseIndex is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Array.forEach` doesn't return anything. You can use `Array.some` and `Array.includes` instead. `Object.values(eligibilityMap).some(arr => arr.includes("SPOUSE"))`

Comment: Object.values is not supported by ie9

Comment: Use polyfills then. Also, IE9....??? And why is this tagged with ES6 then?

Comment: Array.some works

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(eligibilityMap).map(function (key) { return eligibilityMap[key]; })` instead of `.values()`

Comment: If you want to target a very specific environment *at least* mention it in the question. I've changed the tags for you. EDIT: Oops, my sincere apologies. You did mention it in the question. Don't use quote markup for something that's not a quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple approach, supports in all browsers including IE:

```js
    var spouseExists = false;
    var spouseNumber;
    for(var key in eligibilityMap)
    {
      for(var index in eligibilityMap[key])
      {
        if (eligibilityMap[key][index].indexOf("SPOUSE") > -1)
        {
          spouseExists = true;
          spouseNumber = eligibilityMap[key][index].replace("SPOUSE", '');
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(spouseExists, spouseNumber);
```

Comment: `find(elem => ` It looks like arrow function :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: do 3 steps**

1. You can use `flatMap` to get all sub-array into one.
2. use `findIndex` combined with `startsWith` to get exactly the index of `SPOUSE`
3. assign 2 variables based on the value of the found index.

```js
const eligibilityMap = { "CHIP": [ "CHILD5" ], "APTC/CSR": ["SELF1","CHILD2","CHILD3","SPOUSE4"]};
let SpouseExits = false, SpouseIndex = 0; 
const arrays = Object.values(eligibilityMap).flatMap(r => r);
const index = arrays.findIndex(str => str.startsWith("SPOUSE"));

if(index >= 0){
  SpouseExits = true;
  SpouseIndex = arrays[index].slice(-1);
}
  
console.log({SpouseExits, SpouseIndex});
```

**Solution 2: This function renders in IE9 as well**

```js
const eligibilityMap = { "CHIP": [ "CHILD5" ], "APTC/CSR": ["SELF1","CHILD2","CHILD3","SPOUSE4"]};
let SpouseExits = false, SpouseIndex = 0; 

for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(eligibilityMap))
{
  const index = value.findIndex(function(str){ return str.startsWith("SPOUSE")});
  if(index >= 0){
    SpouseExits = true;
    SpouseIndex = value[index].slice(-1);
  }
}

console.log({SpouseExits, SpouseIndex});
```

Comment: @ Nguyễn Văn Phong -- Object.entries, startsWith, .. are not supported by ie9.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `element.indexOf('SPOUSE') >= 0` is not matching any value spouse on your array, because your array has no value named spouse `SPOUSE` it has `SPOUSE4` though.
that's why it's returning undefined.

You may use regex instead of direct matching,

```
Object.keys(eligibilityMap).reduce(function (acc, key) {
const array1 = eligibilityMap[key];
//console.log('array1', array1);
// array1.forEach(element => console.log(element.indexOf('SPOUSE')))
// var spouseExist = -1;
var spouseExist = array1.filter(function (element,index) {

  if(element.match(/SPOUSE/g)) return element; //fixes
});

//fixes
console.log('spouseExist',spouseExist.length>0)
if(spouseExist.length>0){
    spouseExist.forEach(element => {
        console.log('spouseIndex',element[element.length-1])
    });
}
return acc;
```

}, {});

you can get the number from the spouse name directly, or you can access the index number of the matching spouse from inside the filter function using the value of `index` and do whatever you like.
Hope this matches your requirement.